# Display image while populating c# object from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, load

```
response = service.getInfo(request);
```

How can I display an image while my response object is being populated?  Service is a web service located on another server that I have no control over.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This needs a lot more information!

Comment: You could use the asynchron methods of the web service, and hide the image when the asynchron completion event is fired.

Comment: @Hawxby - what else does it need?

Comment: @Uwe - do you have an example?

Comment: Well a bit of detailing as to how you would like to do it. For example in such a situation I may default my page to a loading state then fire an ajax request either back to my application or the 3rd party service to download the data. Once the data has finished downloading then I would use jQuery to make whatever changes needed, remove the image, etc. When a new request is fired I'd set it up to display the loading image, rinse and repeat

Comment: @divided Sorry, I was assuming Windows Forms.

Comment: @Hawxby - I'd like to just use a while() and display the image while the content is loading.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is one way to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877951/how-can-i-defer-loading-updatepanel-content-until-after-the-page-renders)

The bottom line is that you will need some asynchronous process going on.  And that implies AJAX.  The library or methodology you use is up to you.