# Execute Javascript only on page load, not PostBack (SharePoint)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, peoplepicker

I'm trying to execute some JavaScript on page load on a custom page on a SharePoint site (it populates the people picker with the current user). The problem is that the code executes on postback too, which I don't want as it will reset any changes to the people picker.

I've tried using `if(!IsPostBack)` to no avail. Everything errors out at that point, giving

> SCRIPT5009: 'IsPostBack' is undefined.

I can't find anything online to help with this. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `IsPostBack` is available in server side code, just clarifying, are you using that in `javascript`?

Comment: Yes. But I can't get it to work

Comment: I mean since that is available in server side code supporting property, you can not use that in `javascript`, rather look out the answer posted., if that does not work, let me know, i will try to post answer.

Comment: Since it's on SharePoint, I don't have access to the codebehind. A co-worker shared a bit of code they have used that checks the document referrer. That function is working for me now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

> You can create a function like this:

```
function IsPostBack() {
    var ret = '<%= Page.IsPostBack%>' == 'True';
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works - brilliant!  I have been searching long and hard for a way to get my UpdatePanel content to be displayed immediately after (initial content display/) Page Load.  That was fairly straightforward but the UI flickered because it was continually looping causing page loads - but no more! Thank you MrCADMan! :)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the below. Use the JavaScript `pageLoad` method and use the `isInAsyncPostBack` Property of the `PageRequestManager` object to determine whether it's a postback. Refer the MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383989(v=vs.100).aspx) for more details.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    if (!Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {

     // call you JavaScript function in here

    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: With this, it is running on pageload and postback

Comment: Are you sure the js function is not being referenced from elsewhere in the code?

Comment: It works for me when I tried this locally. If it's not working for you then you may have to post some of your custom page code and the JS code.

Comment: I'm really new at all of this. Defining IsPostBack in the page worked for me

Answer (score 3):

`IsPostBack` is not a javascript variable, it's a .NET webforms variable that is only available on the server so the client will complain about it. So what to do then? I suggest this mish-mash in your control's html:

```
<% if(IsPostBack) { %> <!-- runs on server -->

<script type="text/javascript">
 alert('will only be printed to html if not postback');
</script>

<% } %> <!-- ends server if-block -->
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wrongly thinking it was a javascript variable. That was the root issue